# Question on finding the value of x

Tags: multinomial-coefficients

If the coefficient of $x^2$ in the expansion of $(k+ \frac 1 3 x)^5$ is $30$. What is the value of the constant $k$?

Comment: Use the binomial theorem.

Comment: what is the easiest way to do the binomial theorem?

Comment: See Andre Nicolas's answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Hint:** The term in $t^2$ in the binomial expansion of  $(s+t)^5$ is $\binom{5}{2}s^3t^2$. So the term in $x^2$ in the expansion of $\left(k+\frac{x}{3}\right)^2$ is $\binom{5}{2}k^3 \frac{x^2}{9}$. It follows that the coefficient of $x^2$ is $\frac{10k^3}{9}$.

**Remark:** The full expansion of $(s+t)^5$ is 
$$\binom{5}{0}s^5t^0+\binom{5}{1}s^4t+\binom{5}{2}s^3t^2+\binom{5}{3}s^2t^3+\binom{5}{4}st^4+\binom{5}{5}s^0t^5,$$
 or more simply $s^5+5s^4t+10s^3t^2+10s^2t^3+5st^4+t^5$.

In your course, the binomial coefficient $\binom{5}{2}$ may be called $C^5_2$. or ${}^5C_2$, or $C(5,2)$. And there are other notations!

Comment: once you do the binomial theorem, what do you do next?...like the process?

Comment: @Roslyn $30 = \dfrac{5!\, k^3}{2!\,3!\, 9} \implies k = \boxed{\;?\;}$

Comment: To finish, set $\frac{10k^3}{9}=30$. Algebra gives $k^3=27$ so $k=3$.